# How can I via xquery filtering get the whole xml file and not only the nodes that correspond to the filtering?

Tags: filtering, xquery, basex

Is it possible to get the the aggregated xml file using filtering in xquery?

I have the following xquery command

```
xquery declare default element namespace  \"http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common\"; collection('vagelisdb')/SensorInfo/Position[x>4]
```

I get the filtered nodes but they include only a part of the xml, not the whole xml.

```
<Position xmlns="http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common"><x>10</x><y>12</y><z>20</z><Unit>Meters</Unit></Position>
```

I want to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SensorInfo xmlns="http://www.satisfactory-project.eu/XMLSchema/v1.0/common">
<ID>sensor_1</ID>
<Type>DepthCamera</Type>
<Position>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>12</y>
    <z>20</z>
    <Unit>Meters</Unit>
</Position>
<Space>Edw</Space>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you just need to use the document as the predicate context node instead of that  element:

```
collection('vagelisdb')[SensorInfo/Position/x>4]
```